# How is the percentage change 63% when Non-GAAP EPS in Q1 is 0.77 and the same in Q2 is 1.08 and the same in Q2 2019 is 0.66?

Tags: balance-sheet, earnings-per-share

I was just reading the earnings call transcript of ebay.

[2020 Q1 earnings call](https://www.fool.com/earnings/call-transcripts/2020/04/29/ebay-inc-ebay-q1-2020-earnings-call-transcript.aspx) says Non-GAAP eps is 0.77.
[image]

[2020 Q2 earnings call](https://www.fool.com/earnings/call-transcripts/2020/07/28/ebay-inc-ebay-q2-2020-earnings-call-transcript.aspx) says Non-GAAP eps is 1.08. and it says that it is up by 63 %.

I was just trying to understand how they write different components and what they compare it with.

Then it says "Turning to EPS on Slide 11. In Q2, we delivered $1.08 of non-GAAP EPS, up 63% versus the prior year"

But even then if we compare it with [Non-GAAP EPS In Q2 2019](https://ebay.q4cdn.com/610426115/files/doc_financials/financials/2019/q2/2Q19-EBAY-Earnings.pdf) it is 58%.
[image]

I am just confused about how they arrived at 63%.

I think I am missing something here. Can someone help ?

Comment: Look at transcripts or financial statements since Q2 2019. Were there any adjustments that would affect the Q2 2019 EPS? What do you mean by "how they write different components and what they compare it with"?

Comment: Because I don't know what they compared the Q2 EPS will and came with the number 63% high.